# ways to check if datetime is valid

Tags: c#, datetime

I searched in SO, but was not able to find responses that would work for me.

I have a dateTime value in c# and I would like to check if its got a valid value .For example if the following value is passed to datetimeupdate(which is of type datetime) I should be able to throw an exception .

```
datetimeupdate=  2015-07-29T19:55:10.994sdfsdf
```

I tried using Tryparse but it accepts string as the first parameter. But the  datetimeupdate parameter is of type datetime. I am not sure how to check if the parameter has valid value.

I cannot do front end validition as this is in WebAPI and thats the value I get(with invalid characters)

Comment: If its a type of datetime, then it has to be valid, you can't add invalid data to a datetime structure... where does the "sdfsdf" come from?

Comment: Please post code that 1. compiles and 2. shows the problem you are talking about.

Comment: The only validity you can check for on a `DateTime` is stuff like "cannot be in the future" or "cannot be more than 100 years ago".  What you are showing looks like a `string` and `DateTime.TryParse` will return false for that value.

Answer (score 1):

What you have a string representation of a datetime. You can use `TryParse()` method like below; which will return `TRUE` if parsing succeeds.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "2015-07-29T19:55:10.994sdfsdf";
        Console.WriteLine(IsvalidDateTime(str));

    }

    static bool IsvalidDateTime(string date)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        return DateTime.TryParse(date, out dt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
        string d = "2015-07-29T19:55:10.994sdfsdf";
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(d);

        Console.WriteLine(dt);
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Date is InValid ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` is a lazy implementation of the `DateTime.Parse`-method; and should generally be avoided if not absolutely needed.   
    
Source:   http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1724

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` formats quite extensively between different countries/regions.
For instance here in Sweden we follow the `ISO 8601`-format — `yyyy-MM-dd`. In the US, the standard format is `M/d yyyy`

So as for a the "validity" of a date; it's hard to say.
One might describe the date as `2015-07-29T19:55:10.994sdfsdf`. 
And it could be valid if your program could handle (and parse) that input.

The easiest solution to your problem is to use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` (if you know what format your date is in)

```
string dateString = "2015-07-30 18:00:00.142"
string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"


DateTime parsedDate;

bool parseSuccess = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    s: dateString, 
    format: dateFormat, 
    provider: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
    style: DateTimeStyles.None, 
    result: out parsedDate
);

if (parseSuccess)
{
    // valid
}
else 
{
    // not valid
}
```

If the format of the string-representation of the `DateTime` is unknown, you may use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse`.

```
string dateString = "2015-07-30 18:00:00.142"
DateTime parsedDate;

if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out parsedDate))
{
    // valid
}
else 
{
    // not valid
}
```

However, even though used quite extensively — these come with no guarantee of parsing a "correct" date, since the end-user might have entered the date in a different format than expected. And you might end up with the hours in place of the months; which could have some quite unexpected consequences.

**Some reading**

- [Custom DateTime-formats.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx)